# how to show publish version in a textbox?

Tags: c#

At the moment I am manually updating the version field (`textbox`) in my application every time I publish it. I am wondering if there is a way to have my application get that data from somewhere and display it in the box for me. I am using VS2012 and I am just unsure of how to achieve that in C#. Below is a screenshot of the VS2012 properties window that I am talking about.

[image: Publish image from VS2012]

NEW IMAGE:

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Don't forget to check if the application is networkdeployed otherwise it won't work in debug mode.

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    this.Text = string.Format("Your application name - v{0}",
        ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString(4));
}
```

Comment: `IsNetworkDeployed` returns false.. what can the problem be?

Comment: When you are running the debug version under the IDE, then by definition you will not be network deployed, and `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion` will throw `System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException`, that's why you have to check for `IsNetworkDeployed`.  To test that this is working, publish it to the network and then deploy it!  Alternatively, you can try `Application.ProductVersion` as per the answer from @Christos Lytras.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

public Version AssemblyVersion 
{
    get
    {
        return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
    }
}
```

Then the caller to the getter property can de-reference the `Major`, `Minor`, `Build` and `Revision` properties, like this:

```
YourVersionTextBox.Text = AssemblyVersion.Major.ToString() + "."
                        + AssemblyVersion.Minor.ToString() + "."
                        + AssemblyVersion.Build.ToString() + "."
                        + AssemblyVersion.Revision.ToString();
```

Comment: I attempted your suggestion, however in the try block the applicationdeployment is getting an error "system.windows.forms.application does not contain a definition for applicationdeployment" even after including the "using" sections

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Deployment.dll` in your Windows Forms project?

Comment: I do indeed, which I find puzzling that it's having issues with it to begin with.

Comment: I added an image to the question, it won't let me compile the application,

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Deployment;

that is my using lines, and deployment is in my references

Comment: D'oh, just realized that Application is the namespace and the using needs to be `System.Deployment.Application;`, updating answer. Also, your property needs to return `Version` instead of `string`, because `Version` contains the `Major`, `Minor`, `Build` and `Revision` properties that you want to replicate in your textbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33604/discussion-between-shane-superfly-macneill-and-karl-anderson)

Comment: I just tried this approach and i get the following error `
Additional information: Application is not installed.`  . How do i Use that code if im in debug mode?

Comment: @Zapnologica - it would be best if you asked your own question, detailing where you put the code and in what context you are trying to use this code.

Comment: This will only work if the application is network deployed (like via clickonce). You should do a check before accessing `CurrentVersion`. `if(ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)..`

Answer (score 8):

Also we can use overloaded`ToString` of `System.Version`

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

public Version AssemblyVersion 
{
    get
    {
        return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
    }
}


YourVersionTextBox.Text = AssemblyVersion.ToString(1); // 1 - get only major
YourVersionTextBox.Text = AssemblyVersion.ToString(2); // 1.0 - get only major, minor
YourVersionTextBox.Text = AssemblyVersion.ToString(3); // 1.0.3 - get only major, minor, build
YourVersionTextBox.Text = AssemblyVersion.ToString(4); // 1.0.3.4 - get only major, minor, build, revision
```

Comment: AssemblyVersion != Deployment version

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 :**
You can use this

```
string version = Application.ProductVersion;
```

and show the **version** in your textBox.

**Method 2 :**
or if you want the version parts separately, you can use this :

```
System.Version version2 = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

now you have these :

```
version2.Major;
version2.Minor;
version2.Revision;
version2.Build;
```

and you can use them like this

```
string versionString= (String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version2.Major, version2.Minor, version2.Revision, version2.Build));
```

Comment: This is Assembly version, not publish version

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error of `ApplicationDeployment`, then you can try this:

For global version accessing through `Program`, declare inside `Program` class:

```
private static Version version = new Version(Application.ProductVersion);

public static Version Version
{
    get
    {
        return version;
    }
}
```

Now you have `Program.Version` anywhere available in the program and you can use it to get version information like this:

```
LabelVersion.Text = String.Format("Version {0}.{1}",
    Program.Version.Major.ToString(),
    Program.Version.Minor.ToString());
```