# How to bind the "publish version" property in visual studio WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, data-binding

When I'm using the publish option in Visual Studio to create an .*exe package of my application, I can change the **Publish Version** and it starts from 1.0.0.0.

Every time I'm changing something and re-publish it, the version number is increment automatically, and I want to bind that property to a TextBlock in my WPF.

How can I do that?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: i think it is duplicated with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690378/how-to-show-publish-version-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have to reference in your project to `System.Deployment.dll` than you can try this code:

```
    public string PublishVersion
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                Version ver = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
                return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ver.Major, ver.Minor, ver.Build, ver.Revision);
            }
            else
            {
                return "Not Published";
            }
        }
    }
```

Remember that will be work only when you have installed your app.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not entered to the if condition because my "IsNetworkDeployed" is false. Why is that?

Comment: You have to publish your app, install it and than check on working app, you can't check it inside VS.