# how to get the automatically incremented publish revision number

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to read the automatically incremented publish version revision number by code and use it so I can display it on a splash screen.

On the picture the Revision number is number 58.
I use Vb.net, Visual Studio 2013.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't use "assembly version" instead?

Comment: Because it does not increment automatically?

Comment: I only wanted to say that usually its better to control real changes on code, and it's easily readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show publish version in a textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690378/how-to-show-publish-version-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Ok, I test a lot and assembly version is always 1.0.0.0. I would like to be able to see the incremented number so I know I use the right version of files in application files.

Comment: I tried that and it gives: "Version 1.00"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89279/discussion-between-gio-sof-and-capitan-cavernicola).

Answer (score 0):

In fact the solution:

[how to show publish version in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690378/how-to-show-publish-version-in-a-textbox)

does work in the compiled, published executable. But not during debugging.

remember to add "System.Deployment" as a reference to your project (under the .NET tab of "Add Reference").

example vb.net:

```
 If System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed   
 Then
      TextBoxVersion.Text =   
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString
End If
```