# How to define value for C# preprocessor symbol?

Tags: c#

In C# one can define a preprocessor symbol like

```
#define DEBUG
```

How can I set a value, I wish to do something like this

```
#define VERSION = "X.Y.Z"
```

Is it possible ? If yes how can I get its value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Victor said, C# doesn't have support for anything but boolean logic for `#defines`.

If you are looking for setting symbols from the project settings, use Resources (such as string resources) to do that.

If you are setting a version number of an application, the "Publish" tab of the project properties is one way of setting it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690378/how-to-show-publish-version-in-a-textbox) for a way to access it.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot assign a value to a conditional compilation symbol but you can use conditionally defined constants.

```
#define DEBUG

...

#if DEBUG
    const string Version = "X.Y.Z";
#else
    const string Version = "A.B.C";
#end if
```